# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str' (AWS lambda)

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I am writing a function in AWS lambda to extract monthly unemployment data from some Spanish cities.
The code when I try it in local works perfectly, but when I do it in lambda, I get that error. The only difference is that in local I use Python 3.7 and in lambda I have Python 3.6 (I had to do it this way to make it compatible with some modules that I included in the development package.
After some research, it seems that the error comes from mixing operators and strings, but I can't think of another way to express it as I need to, and I emphasize that in local it works perfectly.

Specifically, the line of code that gives this error is:

```
data5.to_csv("s3://xxx/xxx/ '+ str(i).split("/")[-1] + str(fecha) + '.csv'")
```

I have to express it this way because I need you to save every csv with the name of the city and the date of the last updated data. The complete code to understand why I have expressed it this way is this one.

```
Row_list=[]
    MUNICIPIOS = ['https://datosmacro.expansion.com/paro/espana/municipios/andalucia/cadiz/cadiz', 'https://datosmacro.expansion.com/paro/espana/municipios/la-rioja/la-rioja/agoncillo', 'https://datosmacro.expansion.com/paro/espana/municipios/castilla-leon/leon/bembibre']
    for i in MUNICIPIOS:
        data5 = pd.read_html(i, header = 0, decimal=',', thousands='.')
        data5 = data5[0]
        data5 = data5[["Fecha", "Tasa de Paro Registrado", "Nº de parados registrados", "Población"]]
        for index, rows in data5.iterrows():
            my_list =[rows.Fecha] 
            Row_list.append(my_list)
        fecha=[Row_list[0]]
        data5.to_csv("s3://xxx/xxx/ '+ str(i).split("/")[-1] + str(fecha) + '.csv'")
```

Can you think of a way to fix it? I haven't been able to fix it in a while.
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: You are opening a double quote and trying to close it with a single quote here: `"s3://xxx/xxx/ '`. The end part isn't balanced either: `+ '.csv'"`. Please use a proper IDE while writing Python code to spot such errors.

Comment: for index, rows in enumerate(data5.iterrows()): isn't it...? I have not seen two variables in data5 to unpack.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I opened and closed it with single quotes, But I understand that for boto3 to directly store the csvs in those buckets, you have to add the extra quotes at the beginning and at the end.

Comment: @AlejandroMarín You need `'"s3 ...` at the start and `... csv"'` at the end to get a double-quoted string.

Comment: @AlejandroMarín No you don't. Even if you should you are not doing it right anyway.

Comment: Thank you all very much! Indeed, thinking that I needed the quotes in duplicate for S3, I misquoted it. Now I have another error, but well, I start to start it since this error has disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is mismatched quotes. Replace the line of code that gives you an error with this:

```
data5.to_csv("s3://xxx/xxx/ "+ str(i).split("/")[-1] + str(fecha) + ".csv")
```

It is important that you close strings with the same type of quote you opened them with.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm ashamed that it was such a silly mistake

Comment: No worries! It happens to the best of us.